# Change folder permissions using InstallAnywhere

Tags: windows, installanywhere

How can I change folder permissions on Windows using InstallAnywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nobody answered yet, I found a possible solution.

On `Install` menu, click on `Add Action...` | `Execute Command`.

Fill the `Command Line` field with:

```sh
takeown /r /d y /f "\my_folder\*"
```

Add another *Execute Command Action* with:

```sh
icacls "\my_folder" /t  /grant Everyone:F
```

Anybody found a easier way to do that?